# Auto completing the \begin{....}

Tags: texstudio, auto-completion

Previously, before installing the version 4.2 for texstudio, I was able to write `\begin{...` and press enter for studio to write automatically

```
\begin{*environment-name*}
    content...
\end{*environment-name*}
```

This version still does it. But when I wrote something else for  `*environment-name*` part, studio is no longer writes the same thing for the \end `*environment-name*` part. How can I activate this function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known bug, see this [issue](https://github.com/texstudio-org/texstudio/issues/2063) on GitHub. It is already fixed, so in the next version the problem will no longer exist. If you don't want to wait, you can download the latest [beta version](https://github.com/texstudio-org/texstudio/releases/tag/4.2.1beta1), which no longer has this bug.